# Solution of first order inexact differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have following differential equation before me:
$(2y sin(x)+3y^4 sin(x)cos(x))dx-(4y^3 cos^2(x)+cos(x))dy=0$
It is an inexact differential equation. Its Integrating factor comes out to be $cos(x)$.

New $M= 2ysin(x)cos(x)+3y^4sin(x)cos^2(x)$

New $N= -(4y^3cos^3(x)+cos^2(x))$
When I integrate $M$ treating $y$ as a constant, there are more than one way of doing this.

The term $2sin(x)cos(x)$ in $M$ can be integrated to give either $sin^2(x)$ or $-cos(2x)/2$ which differ by a constant. Also in $N$,$cos^2(x)$ could be written either as $1-sin^2(x)$ or $(1+cos(2x))/2$ giving the terms which do not contain $x$ as either $1$ or $1/2$.

All these integrands yield different solutions. I am confused as to which one of these is the correct solution? Are all of them correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$-\dfrac {\cos (2x) }2=\dfrac 12 (2\cos^2  x-1)=\dfrac 12(1-2\sin^2 x)$$
All the constants are absorbed by the constant on the right side of the solution:
$$F(x,y)=C$$

---

$$(2y \sin(x)+3y^4 \sin(x)\cos(x))dx-(4y^3 \cos^2(x)+\cos(x))dy=0$$
$$y d(\cos^2x)+y^4 d(\cos^3(x))+ \cos^3(x)dy^4+cos^2(x)dy=0$$
$$ d(y\cos^2x)+d(y^4\cos^3(x))=0$$
After integration:
$$\boxed {y\cos^2x+y^4\cos^3(x)=K}$$

The constant on the right side absorbs all the constants so all the solutions are equivalent and correct.

---

I am not sure to clearly understand the problem but let's integrate the way you did:
$$M= 2y\sin(x)\cos(x)+3y^4\sin(x)\cos^2(x)$$
We have that
$$\partial_x F=M$$
$$F= \int Mdx$$
$$F=\int 2y\sin(x)\cos(x)+3y^4\sin(x)\cos^2(x)dx$$
Don't forget the constant of integration:
$$F=y\sin^2(x)-y^4\cos^3(x)+\color{red}{g(y)}$$
$$F=-y\cos^2(x)-y^4\cos^3(x)+\color{red}{g(y)+y}$$
$$F=-y\cos^2(x)-y^4\cos^3(x)+\color{red}{h(y)}$$
Do the same for $N$:
$$F =\int  -(4y^3\cos^3(x)+\cos^2(x))dy$$
$$F = -y^4\cos^3(x)-y\cos^2(x) +\color {green}{r(x)}$$

From these two equations about $F$ we deduce that $h(y)=r(x)=c$. So that the solution is now:
$$F(x,y)=K$$
$$y^4\cos^3(x)+y\cos^2(x) =\color {green}{C}$$
It ends with the same answer as we find before.

Comment: When we take $sin^2(x)$ as the integral of $2 sin(x)cos(x)$ and $1/2$ term from $N$, we get $ycos(2x)+2y^3cos^3(x)=K$ as the solution. And this solution does not give us the original differential equation.

Comment: In a comment, I did show that, once more, you are more than correct ! I hope you do not mind. If you do mind, tell me and I shall delete what I wrote.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I hope you have read my above comment. Why does the solution mentioned therein fail to give us the original equation? By the way, there is a typo in that. $y^3$ is actually $y^4$.

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT  Where is the typo ? You mean in my final solution ?

Comment: I completed my answer I hope it's more clear now @HARVEERRAWAT

Comment: @Aryadeva $y^3$ thing refers to my comment. I still have some doubts. Can we go to the chatroom?

Comment: Ok I see  Doubt about what exactly ? @HARVEERRAWAT

Comment: @Aryadeva My doubt comes from the fact that after getting new $M$ and $N$, we integrate $M$ w.r.t.x keeping $y$ as a constant and integrate those terms in $N$ w.r.t.y which do not contain $x$ and putting a constant on the RHS.

Comment: Well I added that in my answer. I have integrated as you did and get the right answer so I don't see clearly where the problem is. I feel I can't help much since I don"t understand the source of the problem. Good Luck. @HARVEERRAWAT

Comment: @Aryadeva I understand the way you have done it. But when I do it the way as my book( M.D. Raisinghania) says, I do not get the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

Consider the implicit function
$$f(x,y)= y\cos^2(x)+y^4\cos^3(x)-k=0$$ as given by @Aryadeva. Then
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=-y \sin (x) \cos (x) \left(3 y^3 \cos (x)+2\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\cos ^2(x) \left(4 y^3 \cos (x)+1\right)$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} } {\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} }=\frac{y \sin (x) \left(3 y^3 \cos (x)+2\right)}{\cos (x) \left(4 y^3 \cos (x)+1\right)}$$ Plug this in the equation
$$(2y \sin(x)+3y^4 \sin(x)\cos(x))-(4y^3 \cos^2(x)+\cos(x))\,y'=0$$ to get $0=0$.